# Artificial limitation in games ver. 2?

Tags: graphics, hardware

> So you've made research? Can you show us that research? You don't seem to be that well-versed in game development or software development in general, so perhaps you misunderstood something.

Just open your eyes. Here it is: without dedicated graphics games use max 50% of each processor's core. And it seems to be an artificial limitation. For a powerful processor 50% is a very big number compared to a powerful graphics card.
Yes It is small. But a large is not needed. Everyone who has a little brain can see that there is no reason to not use 100% of a cpu. Show me the proofs of OVERHEAD

> Because it can not turn into 10 motorcycles.

It was you who said that cpu was suited for many kinds of tasks.

> It would cause your CPU to use more power, which increases your electricity bill.

GPU also uses more power

> Your CPU will run hot when it permanently runs on 100% load, which decreases its lifespan.

A processor's lifespan depends on temperature not on load. Your answers are obviously incorrect so what you are able to explain?

> FWIW, you would get a more beneficial experience out of the site if you registered. That would allow you to have dialogues with other users instead of this one way communication.

You set too many dislikes. But I dont need your site too much. I can askv my questions on some forum

Comment: To quote the [help]: 'To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?” ' If you have a question about how to solve a specific problem you've encountered in developing your own game or game mod, we're happy to help you solve that. If you want to argue for pet theories about how existing games use or misuse hardware, then this is not the site for that purpose.

Comment: I'm locking this; if you feel like continuing to have some kind of discussion on the site, then _register_ and use the site like everyone else.